# NLP/ML classifying only 2 topics unsupervised

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I have a generic question about unsupervised classification of determine labels in a given data set. Let's say I have about 100K documents in a corpus and I want to determine if these documents are either of the 2 labels only. For example, if the document is talking about these particular labels: rain or no-rain; OR war or anti-war; OR religion or anti-religion, ...etc. Is there an algorithm in NLP/Machine Learning domain that could determine without giving supervised learning labels? Any suggestions?

Logistic Regression is supervised otherwise I could have used this as 1 or 0. I don't have labels in my corpus. I thought of Topic Model as well, but TM gives topics amongst the corpus.

Comment: You can try to cluster the document and hope it does what you want. But if you don't have labels how can you know what the documents are talking about ? And how can you tell how well your classification performs ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but try taking a look at topic modeling. Building on top of what @ygorg said, you could perform something like k-means clustering with k = 2, inspect samples of each cluster, annotate those yourself, and perform supervised classification. One caveat though is that I'm not sure if the clusters would come out "clean" or not. You'll probably have to create a dataset using only samples from the "clean" clusters and build on top of that.